# Whitelist file type on vsftpd on CentOS

Tags: centos, ftp, unix, vsftpd

I have CentOS server running on unix, and vsftpd FTP server installed.
I did chroot for users and now I'm trying to limit their file type upload.
I don't want to use deny_file because deny_file limit only few type (and there so many) + deny_file deny from all users including admin.

Is there any way to limit all file type except X,Y,Z?

Answer (score 1):

There is no white list option for [VSFTPD](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) (or [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/)). The best you could probably do is to use `deny_file` in conjunction with `user_config_dir`. The `user_config_dir` directive specifies a directory that contains per user configuration files. Directives in these configuration files override the main server configuration.

Comment: ProFTPD _does_ have a whitelist capability with its [`PathAllowFilter`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#PathAllowFilter).

Comment: Lots can happen in 5 years.